# EntityFramework LINQ Order using string and nested reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, lambda, linq-to-entities

I saw already some of the similar questions, but cannot find an anwser how to solve this problem.
I want to have a possibility to order collection using string as property name.

Model:

```
public sealed class User : IdentityUser
{
    #region Constructors

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Superior")]
    public string SuperiorId { get; set; }

    public User Superior{ get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => this.LastName + " " + this.FirstName;

    #endregion
}
```

And I want to make a call like this:

```
DbSet.Order("SuperiorUser.FullName", Asc/Desc)...
```

My below functions work for a `Order("FullName", Asc/Desc)`, but dont when I want to go deeper.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Order<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName,
    ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
    return ListSortDirection.Ascending == direction
        ? source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName))
        : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}

private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);
}
```

So I made it look a little bit like this

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    var type = typeof(T)
    ParameterExpression parameter;
    MemberExpression property;
    for (var propName in propertyNames)
    {
        parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
        property = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
        type = property.Type;
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);
}
```

But this unfortunately returns error `The parameter '' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression`. What am I missing?

Comment: Your new `ToLambda` won't compile.

Comment: Maybe, I was testing it in debugging watch and wrote it a little quick in here. But you get the point.

Comment: Not really, no - it doesn't make sense to me (e.g. what do you expect to happen to `property` each time around the loop?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest the `Property` access methods in the loop and then apply the parameter to the lambda.

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName) {
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = parameter;
    foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
        body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws: `the specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in linq to entities`

Comment: What happens when you try to use the lambda manually and directly?

Comment: Sorry, that was an understatement. This function works and the return is fine. This part throws this error: `DbSet.Order("SuperiorUser.FullName", Asc/Desc)...`

Comment: My bad, even `.Order()` works fine. The thing was that I was trying to order by a `[NotMapped]` property which is FullName. When I use LastName it works fine. Any idea how to use FullName?

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki Would need to know more about `FullName` - your model just shows a string field.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki You can't do an EF query against an unmapped property - there is no SQL mapping so EF can't sent it to the database. You would need to do `AsEnumerable()` just before the `Order` method call. Alternatively you can start creating more of LINQKit so you can use expandable methods in queries, but at that point why not just use LINQKit?

Comment: I think I will stick to the ordering by `LastName` in this case. Although I will keep in minde LINQKit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542031/ef-order-by-nullable-datetime-using-string-and-nested-reflection

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a extention method for IQueryables to sort by a property defined by string:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    else
    {

        if (propertyName.EndsWith(" ASC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            propertyName = propertyName.Replace(" ASC", "");

        // DataSource control passes the sort parameter with a direction
        // if the direction is descending           
        int descIndex = propertyName.IndexOf(" DESC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (descIndex >= 0)
        {
            propertyName = propertyName.Substring(0, descIndex).Trim();
        }

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, String.Empty);
        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

        string methodName = (descIndex < 0) ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        Expression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                                                                                new Type[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
                                                                                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression) as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
    }
}
```

You may call then LIST.AsQueryable().SortBy("Surname").