# EF Order by Nullable DateTime using string and nested reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, lambda, linq-to-entities

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895095/entityframework-linq-order-using-string-and-nested-reflection) I have created my methods for ordering data sets.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Order<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName,
    ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
    return ListSortDirection.Ascending == direction
        ? source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName))
        : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}

private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = propertyNames.Aggregate<string, Expression>(parameter, Expression.Property);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object)), parameter);
//            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
}
```

It was fine until I have tried to use it with `Nullable<DateTime>`, I have called `Expression.Convert` to box the `Nullable<DateTime>`, but unfortunately it throws

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

I would like to make this more generic, but cannot came with a good idea.

I have done this, but it's dumb AF :D

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Order<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName,
    ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
    if (propertyName.Contains("date", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return ListSortDirection.Ascending == direction
            ? source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T, DateTime?>(propertyName))
            : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T, DateTime?>(propertyName));

    }
    return ListSortDirection.Ascending == direction
        ? source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T, object>(propertyName))
        : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T, object>(propertyName));
}

private static Expression<Func<T, A>> ToLambda<T, A>(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = propertyNames.Aggregate<string, Expression>(parameter, Expression.Property);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, A>>(Expression.Convert(body, typeof(A)), parameter);
//            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Does it work with DateTime? If it does, just use the Value of the Nullable<DateTime> to order.

Comment: Hmmm, you could try to CAST it in `(DateTime)`, but it will result in null value being probably turned into DateTime.MinValue... which is not all that great

Comment: @MBakardzhiev 1st part of code doesn't work with DateTime, afaik it works only with primitives.