# Building a Linq sort expression from string results in 'Expression of "system.int32" can not be used for return type "System.Object" '

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, .net-6.0

I have a system that should create a sort expression based on a list of sort data that is supplied from another application. The sort info is given as an object that contains a sort key (Object.thingtosort) and a direction.

My current solution was built around a solution I got from another stack overflow question, found over here: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895095/entityframework-linq-order-using-string-and-nested-reflection/48895683#48895683). Whenever I run the following code:

```
    static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        Expression body = parameter;
        foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
            body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter); //<-- line of error
        return func;
    }
```

I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object''
```

I tried solving this by converting the parameter to an Object by using

```
    Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
```

Resulting in the following function:

```
static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        Expression body = parameter;
        foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
            body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
        var convertedBody = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedBody, parameter); //<-- line of error
        return func;
    }
```

This Creates creates another problem where it fails to compare two elements in the array (probably because it doesn't know how to compare object to object in this case).

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.'
ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

I want it to work with any type, as the sorting should work on any field of my object (these can be nested multiple layers deep). Included below is the full code required to recreate my problem.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1

The project is a console application using .net 6.

```
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

            string propertyForExpression = "Product.randomNumber";

            Random random = new Random();

            List<OrderEntity> orders = new List<OrderEntity>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                var orderToAdd = new OrderEntity();
                orderToAdd.id = i;
                orderToAdd.name = "order number " + i;

                var productToAdd = new ProductEntity();
                productToAdd.id = i;
                productToAdd.productName = "product " + i;
                productToAdd.description = "this is a product";
                productToAdd.randomNumber = random.Next(1, 100);

                orderToAdd.Product = productToAdd;
                orders.Add(orderToAdd);
            }

            var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(X => ToLambda<OrderEntity> (propertyForExpression));

            foreach(var order in sortedOrders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(order.Product.randomNumber);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            Expression body = parameter;
            foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
                body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
            var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
            return func;
        }


    // ToLambda function that crashes on the OrderBy with error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.'

    //static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
    //{
    //    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    //    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    //    Expression body = parameter;
    //    foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
    //        body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
    //    var convertedBody = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    //    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedBody, parameter);
    //    return func;
    //}
    }


    public class OrderEntity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public ProductEntity Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductEntity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int randomNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can I suggest you fix the `ToLambda` method at the bottom of your question, as it is currently missing the conversion and I mistakenly thought you were getting the error from there, rather than the `OrderBy`.

Comment: I can add the conversion to the example and change the question to be specifically about that issue. I do also want to keep the question open to solutions that might change something about the signature of the ToLambda function. Do you think the solution is more likely to be related to converting the body to object and then fixing the IComparable issue?

Comment: It's just that it's a little difficult to produce the second issue you're talking about without the code for it.

Comment: I added the edited version of the ToLambda() method as a comment. This way it is possible to switch between the two errors with the same code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is ultimately a minor mistake.

1. You're trying to order by the `Expression<Func<T, object>>` (as in the value of that, not the value of `randomNumber` determines the sort order.
2. `.OrderBy` for enumerables (not queryables) expects a `Func<TSource, TKey>` where `TSource` is `OrderEntity` and `TKey` is supposed to be your `object` value in this case.

So we need to do two things:

1. Compile the expression.
2. Use it for sorting.

Essentially we need this

```cs
Func<OrderEntity, object> sortAccessor = ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression).Compile();
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(sortAccessor);
```

or

```cs
Func<OrderEntity, object> sortAccessor = ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression).Compile();
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(x => sortAccessor(x));
```

or

```cs
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(x => ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression).Compile()(x));
```

or

```cs
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression).Compile());
```

You could also change the method to return the compiled `Func<T, object>` instead:

```cs
static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = parameter;
    foreach (var propName in propertyNames)
        body = Expression.Property(body, propName);

    var convertedResult = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));

    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertedResult, parameter);
    return func;
}
```

and then use it more like this:

```cs
Func<OrderEntity, object> sortAccessor = ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression);
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(sortAccessor);
```

or this:

```cs
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(ToLambda<OrderEntity>(propertyForExpression));
```

**Note:** the reason I'm suggesting compiling the expression outside of the loop and caching it as a `Func<OrderEntity, object>` variable is because otherwise it will be evaluated multiple times for a single `.OrderBy`.

Comment: @bart just be aware (as I mentioned at the bottom of my answer) that this will result in it being compiled many times for a single loop through the orders (you can set a breakpoint in the `ToLambda` method to see how many). If this is going to be handling a large number of orders, or is performance critical, I'd suggest compiling it outside of the `OrderBy`. Perhaps make it an extension method so it still reads neatly.

Comment: In the real code the object is not directly used in a loop. I call a .ToList() after all the sort logic is applied (generally 3 or 4 sorting rounds applied on the IOrderedEnumerable using ThenBy) and the sorted list gets passed on to a processor. I do appreciate you mentioning the performance aspect here because the function will be used for large batches of objects.